# fs.readdirSync found entries that fs.statSync cannot read

Tags: node.js, usb-flash-drive

This is actually an issue found in `recursive-readdir-sync` library.

The device is a flash drive. What happened is that fs.readdirSync returns an array of file name entries some of which fs.statSync would throw error reading.

Fun fact: Doing `$ ls -a` in the shell did not reveal the files that `fs.readdirSync` did.

I am not sure whether this is a known issue of NodeJS or something of even lower level is going on (like OS or the device itself).

**UPDATED**

- OS: MacOS (10.14.1)
- Device: SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD 250GB - 2TB Solid State Drive

Comment: Which OS? Which files?

Comment: I updated the question based on your feedback. General PDF files.